# Python Pyrogram UserBot как закрепить сообщение

Tags: python, pyrogram

У меня есть код:

```py
@app.on_message(filters.command("pin", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
async def pin(client, message):
    await message.pin(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message_id)
```

Но он не работает и выдает ошибку:

```
NameError: name "message_id" Is not defined
```